# category displays products horizontally in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, product, categories, woocommerce-theming

I have a website bansisuppliers.co.ke, I have created categories for products but the products display only in an horizontal manner instead of a grid view, that is the categories list products in one row and several columns creating a horizontal bar. I need the products to display in grid form with respect to the website layout

Answer (score 0):

it must be something wrong with the styling.
try using

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

to your categories.php
and apply the style on page_id of one category for sample
or feel free to share the styles with us.